# How to create an argument object

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

In Python we can create an "arguments object" to call any function that accept such sequence of arguments:

```
args = (42, True, "Hello")

f1(*args)
f2(*args)
```

The problem I'm facing in C++ is that I have a generic function `f` with several arguments and with 16 different specializations, and I'm forced to explicitly tell which version to call by reading the value of an `enum`:

```
switch (type) {
case xtype::BOOL:
  f<bool>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;

case xtype::INT8:
  f<int8_t>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;

case xtype::UINT8:
  f<uint8_t>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;

case xtype::INT16:
  f<int16_t>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;

...

case xtype::FLOAT:
  f<float>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;

}
```

I was recently given another function, `g`, which I also need to call following the same pattern:

```
switch (type) {
case xtype::BOOL:
  g<bool>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
  break;
...
}
```

What is the easiest way to wrap this type-selection code into some generic function? Or, how can I make my life easier when I need to change one argument of `f` or `g`? For example:

```
invoke(type, f, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
invoke(type, g, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg9);
```

The arguments types of `f` and `g` may not the same.

## Update

I added an answer of my own on how I solved this.

Comment: I believe you are looking for *variadic templates*.

Comment: maybe you need to look at boost::tuple, as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

With variadic templates you might build a list of types and dispatch accordingly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class TypeIdentifier
{
    public:
    typedef unsigned Integer;
    enum Value
    {
        Bool = 1,
        Int8,
        UInt8,
        Int32,
        UInt32,
        Int64,
        UInt64,
        Float,
        Double,
        String,
        Unknown = 0
    };

    template <Value ...Ids>  struct ListType {};
    typedef ListType<
        Bool,
        Int8,
        UInt8,
        Int32,
        UInt32,
        Int64,
        UInt64,
        Float,
        Double,
        String,
        // Always the last value:
        Unknown
    >
    List;

    public:
    Integer id;

    TypeIdentifier(Integer value = Unknown)
    :   id(value)
    {}

    template<typename Functor, typename ... T>
    typename Functor::result_type dispatch(const Functor&, T&& ...);
};


// dispatch
// =============================================================================

namespace TypeIdentifierDispatch {

template <typename Functor, TypeIdentifier::Value I, TypeIdentifier::Value ... Ids> struct Evaluate;

template <typename Functor>
struct Evaluate<Functor, TypeIdentifier::Unknown> {
    template <typename ... T>
    static typename Functor::result_type
    apply(TypeIdentifier::Integer id, const Functor&, T&& ... arguments) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown Type");
    }
};

template <typename Functor, TypeIdentifier::Value I, TypeIdentifier::Value ... Ids>
struct Evaluate {
    template <typename ... T>
    static typename Functor::result_type
    apply(TypeIdentifier::Integer id, const Functor& functor, T&& ... arguments) {
        if(id == I) return functor(std::forward<T>(arguments) ...);
        else return Evaluate<Functor, Ids...>::apply(id, functor, std::forward<T>(arguments) ...);
    }
};

template <typename Functor, TypeIdentifier::Value ... Ids, typename ... T>
inline typename Functor::result_type
evaluate(
    TypeIdentifier::Integer id,
    const Functor& functor,
    TypeIdentifier::ListType<Ids...>,
    T&& ... arguments)
{
    return Evaluate<Functor, Ids...>::apply(id, functor, std::forward<T>(arguments) ...);
}

} // namespace TypeIdentifierDispatch

template<typename Functor, typename ... T>
typename Functor::result_type TypeIdentifier::dispatch(const Functor& functor, T&& ... arguments) {
    return TypeIdentifierDispatch::evaluate(
        id,
        functor,
        TypeIdentifier::List(),
        std::forward<T>(arguments) ...);
}

struct Add
{
    typedef double result_type;
    double operator () (double a, double b) const { return a + b; }
};

int main() {
    TypeIdentifier id(TypeIdentifier::Int32);
    std::cout <<  id.dispatch(Add(), 1.0, 1.5) << std::endl;
}
```

Note: In the code above, a functor is involved. You might use a function signature or a std::function instead. kennytm has written some helpful function-traits (See https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp)

Comment: Thank you, your proposal is very interesting yet it seems (to me) overly complex. I added an answer of my own.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a plain old macro to solve my code duplication issue:

```
#define XYZ_DISPATCH_BY_XTYPE(F, T, ...)    \
    switch(T)                               \
    {                                       \
    case xtype::BOOL:                      \
        F<bool>(__VA_ARGS__);               \
        break;                              \
    case xtype::FLOAT:                      \
        F<float>(__VA_ARGS__);               \
        break;                              \
    ....
```

And adding a new function is relatively easy:

```
XYZ_DISPATCH_BY_XTYPE(f1, type, a0, a1, a2, ..., a9)
XYZ_DISPATCH_BY_XTYPE(g1, type, q0, q1, q2, ..., q9)
```

Thank you all on your answers!